# merge 3 tables with some IDs repeating - mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am merging 3 tables with the same structure into one table, but there are some row Id's that are repeating (id 40 in one table and id 40 in other table), so when i try to merge the tables, it gets only one of those 2 rows, and the other row is ignored. Is there a way to get both rows (maybe give a random id for the other row?)

```
replace into table1 
select * 
from table2 
union 
select * 
from table3 
union 
select * 
from table4
```

Comment: This appears to be unrelated to PHP. I updated your post to alter the tags and also format it more clearly.

Comment: Anyway, have you come across `UNION ALL` before? If ID is a field which must be unique though, you'll still have an issue potentially.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution but beware, if you have linked tables to those tables, foreignkeys will have no meaning in this case, you will have to generate them in the other tables.

You can try an insert without the primary key field

```
INSERT INTO Table_1(column1,Column2,column3...)
SELECT column1,Column2,column3... FROM Table_2
UNION
SELECT column1,Column2,column3... FROM Table_3
UNION
SELECT column1,Column2,column3... FROM Table_4
```

If Identity is turned on, the primary key will be generated automatically
You can try to extract the columns easily :

```
SELECT DISTINCT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME='Table_1';
```

I assume tables have the same structure, so you're only doing it once, There is another trick i use in MSSQL.

- Right click on the table and select "Select TOP 1000 ROWS"

It will show the result but also the script with all the table's columns in the query editor, good luck !

If you want to change the starting number of an auto_increment, you can use this query:

```
ALTER TABLE Table_2 AUTO_INCREMENT=2000
```

Comment: I can try this solution later, becouse i have a lot of columns, it would take time to write all that, maybe there is a way where I can say for example in table2 that i want ID's to start from 2000 and auto-increment from that point? So it doesn't start from 1..

Comment: Edited the Answer, to answer what you asked, good luck !

Comment: Yes, i found out about this auto_increment a little before you posted an answer, and it worked, but still will accept your answer for someone that has the same issue. Thanks :)